# PHP - Equals is Not Equals but should be

Tags: php, android, post

Have a bit of a problem with some current code we're using Android to POST to PHP where using the following code

```
$fbid = $_POST['fbid'];

if($fbid == "no"){
echo 'no fbid';
}else{
echo 'fbid look for user';
}
```

We used the following `strlen($fbid)` which returns `2`

All the posted strings don't seem to match and when used strlen() on all equal the correct amount - any ideas? could this be encoding problem?

Comment: did you try echoing `$fbid` to see if it really contains `'no'`? the `==` operator is never going to lie to you.

Comment: Encoding problem seems unlikely because there aren't any non-ASCII characters in "no" (or "yes")

Comment: @sgroves $fbid does echo to 'no' and on strlen returns count of 2

Comment: Does the code always print 'fbid look for user' or it wont work at all ? Plus add semicolon after 'fbid look for user'

Comment: Quite possibly the world's easiest debug missed by okett??

Comment: @BenCarey i dunno, if you're missing a semicolon the script won't run at all, right? it'll give a parse error.

Comment: @sgroves `==` can lie, but not in PHP :)

Comment: @sgroves very true! :-P

Comment: at the beginning of your code, add error_reporting(E_ALL); and check output.

Comment: @BenCarey - There is a ; there. i just edited lines on StackOverflow to make neat

Comment: How is it set?  Can you c/p the html field or the ajax call?

Comment: It's a call from Android app using HttpAsyncClient

Answer (score 0):

Just as a trivial suggestion:

```
if($fbid == "no"){
    echo 'no fbid';
}else{
    echo 'fbid look for user';
}
```